# How to send to multiple addresses in one ethereum tx?

Tags: ethereum, web3js

How can I make bitcoin like transaction in ethereum (web3js particular), when I need to send to multiple addresses defferent amount in one transaction to save fee?

Answer (score 0):

From Péter Szilágyi's [answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/980/is-it-possible-to-send-transactions-to-multiple-recipients) on Ethereum StackExchange, it seems that it is a bit indirect as compared to Bitcoin. One transaction can only have one output, but you can create a smart contract that will be able to send to multiple outputs.